# Why this C code with pipe() suddenly stops?

Tags: c

I am a computer science's student and I have this "Operative Systems" exam nearby, while I was doing some exercises based on my teacher previous exams tracks, I found myself to be stuck on this one.

The track summarized:

> Write a C program with two input files (input.txt and out.txt), the program has to create 2 child processes, the first one will read characters from the inputfile.txt two at a time and will pass them onto child n*2 only if the letters are equal! then will proceed to print them to out.txt.

I didn't do the equals part yet, because i'm stuck on this first while crashing.
I have done several attempts, but they always "freeze" after the first while sequence on V:55 , and I don't understand why the cicle is wrong(?)...

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define MAX 128
#define argDef 3

int checkArgc(int argc);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int pipe1[2], pipe2[2], nbytes, filedesc, pid1, pid2;
    char duelettere[2];
    char soluzione[MAX];
    if (!checkArgc(argc)) {
        printf("Numero di file insufficente!\a\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Qui tutto bene\n");
    /* Apertura file di input.txt */
    if ((filedesc = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        perror("Errore durante l'apertura dei file.txt \a\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("filedesc : %d\n", filedesc);
    if (pipe(pipe1) < 0) {
        perror("Errore durante la creazione della prima PIPE! \a\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("pipe1 : %p\n", pipe1);
    if (pipe(pipe2) < 0) {
        perror("Errore durante la creazione della seconda PIPE! \a\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("pipe2 : %p\n", pipe2);
    if ((pid1 = fork() < 0)) {
        perror("Errore creazione primo processo figlio \a\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid1 == 0) { /* Primo figlio */
        printf("pid1 : %d\n", pid1);
        close(pipe1[0]); /* Chiusura canale in entrata, per poter scrivere */
        while ((nbytes=read(filedesc, duelettere, 2)) == 2) {
            write(pipe1[1], duelettere, 2);
        }
        close(pipe1[1]); /* Chiudiamo la PIPE che stava scrivendo */
        close(filedesc);
    } else { /* Siamo nel processo padre, e lanceremo il figlio n^2 */
        close(pipe1[1]);
    }
    if (pid2 = fork() < 0) {
        perror("Errore creazione secondo figlio\a\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid2 == 0) {
        printf("pid2 : %d", pid2);
        close(pipe1[1]);
        close(pipe2[0]);
        nbytes = read(pipe1[0], soluzione, strlen(soluzione));
        nbytes = write("out.txt", soluzione, strlen(soluzione));
    } else { /* Codice del padre */
        close(pipe2[1]);
        /* Codice finale del padre */
        printf("Siamo arrivati nel padrino parte seconda\n");
    }
    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}

int checkArgc(int argc) {
    if (argc != argDef) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I apologize,
Some variables have italian names on it, because I'm italian.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The `pipe1` and `pipe2` arrays needs to contain two elements and not one, it should be `int pipe1[2], pipe2[2]`

Comment: Oh you're right! I made a mistake here, Update : still crashing.

Comment: `read(filedesc, duelettere, 2)`: you are reading 2 characters into an array of size 1.

Comment: Your example does not compile, there are some missing braces `{}`. Try to indent everything properly and always put the closing braces on a new line.

Comment: `nbytes = read(pipe1[0], soluzione, strlen(duelettere));` also looks wrong.  It doesn't appear that `duelettere` contains a nul-terminated string at this point, and even if it did, I don't see why the length of that string should correspond to the number of characters you want to read.

Comment: Yes the char array was done wrong, i've updated it, and yes braces were not in the right places, now they should be.
Why is the read instruction wrong then?
Maybe i need to do : duelettere[nbytes]='\0'; ?

Comment: `if (filedesc = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY) < 0)` is wrong. It should be `if ((filedesc = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)`. Same thing for `if (pid1 = fork() < 0)` and `if (pid2 = fork() < 0)`.

Comment: That will typically just overwrite the second character you read.  I think it would help to think carefully through what your code does to the bytes in the array.  Don't think about strings, think about bytes.

Comment: This is the output now : 
Qui tutto bene
filedesc : 0
pipe1 : 0x7fffee12721c
pipe2 : 0x7fffee127224
pid1 : 0
pid1 : 0
@NateEldredge ok, i will write a test program only to try this reading 2 letters at a time functions, and see what i'm doing wrong, i'll update here if i find anything.

Comment: Yes @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, those braces were wrong, now the program closes without "freezing" at : [ pid1 : 0 pid1 : 0 ]
The code here has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other problems, but these two lines are definitely incorrect:

```
    if ((pid1 = fork() < 0))
    ...
    if (pid2 = fork() < 0) {
```

You should change them to this:

```
    if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0)
    ...
    if ((pid2 = fork()) < 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me notice this, i've been doing braces wrong in if cases for a long time then... at least better later then ever!